# Load content as an element scrolls into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic-loading

I have a list of search results in a `<div>` element with a static height and `overflow: auto;` in the style. I would like to load only the first x number of search results (e.g. 20), and load another x results as the user scrolls to the bottom of the element containing the search results.

Can anyone explain to me how I would do this? I found a few examples, but all of those use the scroll value of the entire document, not a single `<div>`. I am using jQuery, if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like you'd like to detect the scroll bars position when it is near the end.  [Found this](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/msg/990e00ea899f61d2) when googling around on the jquery group.  Its proposed solution with a little added documentation if needed:

```
$.fn.isNearTheEnd = function() {
  // remember inside of $.fn.whatever = function() {}
  //   this is the jQuery object the function is called on.
  //   this[0] is DOMElement
    return this[0].scrollTop + this.height() >= this[0].scrollHeight;
};

// an example.
$("#content").bind("scroll", function() {
  if ($(this).isNearTheEnd()) // load some content
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the div's `.top() + .height()` to the window's `.scrollTop + .height` then you could tell when you're at the bottom of that div, and then trigger the next content load...